# Hessian matrix always singular in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to implement training an MLP with Newton's method in Theano. I've managed to find out how to obtain the inverse hessian (it's pretty easy, just needed to remove some `assert`s in the `nlinalg` module). However, when I try to update my weight vectors with my `gradient_descent` function, I get the following error:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
Apply node that caused the error: MatrixInverse(InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,1}.0)
```

Obviously, if my hessian is singular, it can't be inverted. But the weights are random, so how come it's always singular? I don't know much about matrix computation, but it seems to me that there must be a flaw in my process. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def gradient_descent(error, weights, w_flat, learning_rate=0.1):
    # decrease flattened weights by the product of the inverse Hessian and the gradient
    hess = T.hessian(cost=error, wrt=[w_flat])
    grad = T.grad(error, wrt=[w_flat])
    mult = T.nlinalg.matrix_inverse(hess) * grad
    update = w_flat - learning_rate * mult

    return T.flatten(update)

#initialize weight matrices
w_h_flat = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.randn(11,6), dtype=theano.config.floatX).flatten())
w_hidden = w_h_flat.reshape((11,6))
w_o_flat = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.randn(7,1), dtype=theano.config.floatX).flatten())
w_output = w_o_flat.reshape((7,1))

# ... other mlp stuff, define the cost, etc ...

train = theano.function(inputs=[x, y], outputs=cost, updates=[(w_h_flat, gradient_descent(cost, w_hidden, w_h_flat)), (w_o_flat, gradient_descent(cost, w_output, w_o_flat))])
```

Would really appreciate any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: *"it's pretty easy, just needed to remove some asserts in the `nlinalg` module"* - you directly edited the `theano/tensor/nlinalg.py` source file to remove some assertions? You'd better show us what you did.

Comment: I just removed `assert x.ndim == 2` on line 69, that's all. I've seen a discussion somewhere (I think it was a github issue) where people have said the linalg module has some assertions that should be removed to make it work. This assert wasn't passing, although it's weird because the Hessian was of course 2-dimensional.

Anyway, in the meantime I found out that the problem is my cost function (`(y - output)**2`). It seems that it always has a singular Hessian. Not sure what to do about it in this context though.

Comment: It would probably be better to reshape the input variable to 2D rather than removing assertions in `ndlinalg` since this is likely to make debugging more painful in the long run. It's hard to say why the Hessian would be singular without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).